# SDL not configured with OpenGL/GLX support

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I have the following code:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE); 

// Create an application window with the following settings:
window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
    640,                               // width, in pixels
    480,                               // height, in pixels
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL  | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE                 // flags - see below
);

// Check that the window was successfully created
if (window == NULL) {
    // In the case that the window could not be made...
    printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}



SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

// Close and destroy the window
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

// Clean up
SDL_Quit();
```

}

After the SDL_CreateWindow call I get the following error:
SDL not configured with OpenGL/GLX support

that's how I compile it:

```
g++ *.cpp -lSDL2
```

I have managed to run this code on another laptop with the same operating system (Ubuntu 20.04.2) and same NVIDIA driver (4.6.0). I can not see the relevant diff between the two systems, so please help me out.

Comment: Can you please check the return value of the function `SDL_Init` (it should return zero on success), otherwise call `SDL_GetError()` to debug the error message ? It can prevent `SDL_CreateWindow()` from working...

Comment: Where did you get your SDL2? Did you compile it yourself?